# EFI dual-boot problem on HP Pavilion 15 with Windows 8 and Debian 8

Tags: debian, boot, partition, dual-boot, uefi

### Context

HP Pavilion 15 Notebook, when I bought it there was Windows 8 pre-installed. 
Yesterday I partitioned my hard disk and I installed a fresh new Debian 8 everything fine, here's the table:

```
root@debian:/# fdisk -l
...
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     821247    819200   400M Windows recovery environ
/dev/sda2      821248    1353727    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1353728    1615871    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1615872  731095039 729479168 347,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1425111040 1465147391  40036352  19,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   731095040 1419251711 688156672 328,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1419251712 1425108991   5857280   2,8G Linux swap
....
```

---

### Problem

*When I press the power button, it boot Windows 8 and not the grub, without letting me choose the OS.*

---

### Further data

My system boot specs:

- Fast boot      -> disabled
- Secure boot    -> disabled
- Legacy boot    -> disabled
- EFI boot       -> enabled

So I can't choose what OS to boot because it starts automatically Win 8, but if I press the button F9 and enter to the BIOS's "Boot order" the following is presented:

```
Boot Option Menu:
- OS boot Manager     -> if pressed starts Windows 8
- debian              -> if pressed starts Grub (that's what i want)
- Boot from EFI File  -> it starts the navigation of a folder that let you choose the .efi file
- Notebook Hard Drive -> I don't remember but I think starts Windows 8
```

So there are strange things happening here... look at my efibootmgr:

```
root@debian:~# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 003D
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,3002,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0003* debian
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

and if I try to change the running sequence with:
    efibootmgr -o 0003,0002

the changes are ignored and Windows 8 still boot without giving choices.

In [this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Changing-Boot-Order-on-Dual-Boot-Windows-8-and-Ubuntu/td-p/2503733) link someone say that the manufacturers hardcoded the fact that `/EFI/Windows/Boot` is checked before `/EFI/debian` so this could be a problem because efi always look for Windows first.

So I mountend my `/dev/sda2` (EFI system) to a `/target` folder to look what's going on, here's what:

```
root@debian:/target# ls
boot  BOOTSECT.BAK  EFI

root@debian:/target/EFI# ls
Boot  debian  HP  Microsoft

root@debian:/target/EFI# ls debian
grubx64.efi

root@debian:/target/EFI# ls Microsoft
Boot

root@debian:/target/EFI# ls Microsoft/Boot/
BCD          boot.stl         es-ES  ko-KR        qps-ploc    
BCD.LOG      bootx64.efi      et-EE  lt-LT        Resources  
BCD.LOG1     bootx64.efi.grb          lv-LV       ro-RO       
BCD.LOG2                      Fonts  memtest.efi  ru-RU       
bg-BG                         en-US  <otherlanguages>
bkpbootmgfw.efi               
bootmgfw.efi                  
bootmgr.efi                  
BOOTSTAT.DAT
```

In [this](http://reboot.pro/topic/19363-efibootmgr-not-changing-boot-order-permanently/) link someone resolved moving and renaming this `/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi` to this `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`

But I'm afraid of:

- Can I recover Windows after this operation?
- Is it safe?
- Someone can explain to me a little bit more about this problem? and tell me the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved, the problem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file), I followed all the steps to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

See here
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=296423&p=1648791#p1648791

& there is a link there to Ubuntu Forum

...
The "OS Boot Manager" is hard coded to load the Microsoft EFI file and will always run before any other local EFI files.
...